# extracting lines matching keywords python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file in the following format:

```
Car: Replace:Brakes<10
Car: Renew: Engine=100000
Truck: Renew: Engine=1000
Truck: Replace: Brakes<504
```

I am looking to write a regex to parse this file and extract only the lines with `Car` in it and also only extract values after Car and return them as a python dictionary.

So my output would look like

```
'Replace' :' Brakes<10'
'Renew' : 'Engine=100000'
```

Any inputs on how I can achieve this?
I tried.

```
re.search
```

but get a re.Match object which I am not sure how to interpret.
Thank you!

Comment: For reference, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) are the docs for `re.Match`.  You'll want to add capture groups and then use the [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) method to extract the text from each group.

Comment: I am not entirely sure where your exact problem lies. Your question might benefit from a [mre].

Comment: Python docs about the "re" module also explain Match objects. By the way: A Python dict can't contain the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

There we go:

https://regex101.com/r/UTdN6B/1

use `^Car: (.*)|.*` as pattern and `\1` as substitute also `gm` as flags.

Comment: This is fantastic. I am bookmarking this link :) Thanks!